# Dynamics 365 - Register a 'Create' step for 'audit' entity

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dynamics-crm

Does anyone know,
Is there any way to catch, in Plugin Registration, step of Create Audit History(audit) record event ?

It is enabled in Dynamics, but I need to perform some actions after the Audit record has been created.

Comment: upvoted, question is relevant for Dynamics 365 development, really sorry for the other downvotes you received

Comment: Voted to reopen as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... The Audit entity prohibits registering steps against its Create message. Considering that Audit is a specialized entity that stores data in a denormalized way, this kind of makes sense.

What are you looking to do with the Audit record?
If you're looking to do anything with the data that changed on the record, you can do that with a pre-image and post-image.

Otherwise, a plugin running asynchronously on the create and update messages of all the audited entities should be able to access the audit record that just got created.